# Best way to implement scheduled push notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm currently developing an app that has some sort of user meetings system,
recently the our product team requested to include some scheduled push notifications that will remind the users that they have a meeting 30 mins before, 10 mins before and 10 minutes into the meeting.
(We use FCM as a push notification service)

Currently for every new meeting we register a cron job on AWS CloudWatch Events rules, but I've come to realize that it's probably not the best way to implement it due to expected large number of registered meetings... (for example if we will have 100 active meetings, we will have 300 registered CloudWatch Events rules...

So my question is there a better way to implement such a service?

EDIT:
The clients are both IOS(Swift) and Anrdoid(Java)

Comment: It may depend on which platform(s) your client app is. Usually, you wouldn't even need to send push notifications. What I'm thinking is, why not just have the app get all the data it needs when it's online, store the schedules locally, then use that data to show a native notification. This way, even if the user isn't online, they would still get a notification. One thing to think about is what if the schedule changes during that window.

Comment: @AL.the clients are native Ios(swift) and Android(Java)

Answer (score 7):

Definitely the best way is to **push or sync the meeting data to the mobile app** and then have the mobile app manage notifications.

If you do need to send notifications directly from the cloud, you should design the system to be highly scalable, capable of handling thousands and even millions of meetings.

The easiest way would probably be to populate a 'notification' table in a database when a meeting is created. Add a row with the time that the user should be notified.

Then, use a schedule on **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to trigger an **AWS Lambda function** each minute. The Lambda function should query the database for any notifications scheduled for this minute (or earlier) that have not been sent. (This allows for retry after failures.)

Send a notification via **Amazon SNS** or **Amazon Pinpoint**. Then, mark the notification as having been sent.

Comment: How is it guaranteed that AWS Lambda function will complete scanning of all items to be notified and send notifications to all those clients within the 1 minute interval?

Comment: @Kans There would be no such guarantee. It could take more than a minute to process those notifications.

Comment: Thanks John. So,I think the best way would be schedule a job a few minutes before the target minute which will scan the DB and find all notifications that need to be sent. This will be passed on to a scheduler which will wait till the final minute comes through and then sends it off to notification dispatcher service.  This will ensure that the notification is sent right on time without any delays (excluding failure cases).